# How to add load more button ajax button to this wordpress loop?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

```
<main class="main aktualitasu_saraksta_konteineris" role="main">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type'             => 'post',
            'posts_per_page'        => -1,
            'group_by'              => 'date',
            'order'                 => 'DESC',
            'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1
        );
        $query = new WP_Query($args);
    ?>

    <?php if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'parts/loop', 'news' ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();?>                           
</main>
```

How to add load more button that load posts with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do this in javascript rather than in php look at this https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp. You will need to add button in html say

```
<button id="load_more" type="button">Load More</button>
```

And then in javascript (this is an example using jQuery)

```
$("#load_more").click(function(){
    $.get("your/route", function(data, status){
        //here you can add the data to the page depending on what the data is 
    });
});
```

your/route is whatever route you have set in php for fetching more posts